# Expand a rational function in a one degree partial fraction, but not include a two degree expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I expand a rational function into a one degree partial fraction, and not include a two degree expression? For example, for

[image]

Apart[] will get

[image]

but I want the following result:

[image]

What shall I do?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are there i's in the result? Are those imaginary numbers?

Comment: Please post *code*, not just images.

Answer (score 7):

```
expr = 1/(-4 - 2 x + 2 x^2 + 3 x^3 + x^4);

expr2 = Factor[expr, GaussianIntegers -> True] // Apart
```

[image]

```
expr == expr2 // Simplify
```

> True

If the denominator cannot be factored with integers or Gaussian integers

```
expr = 1/(x^2 + x + 1);

expr2 = Numerator[expr]/
   (Times @@ (x - (x /.
         Solve[Denominator[expr] == 0, x]))) //
  Apart
```

[image]

```
expr == expr2 // Simplify
```

> True

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when use Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x], we can get {{x -> -(-1)^(1/3)}, {x -> (-1)^(2/3)}}, how to directly apart 1/(x^2 + x + 1) to (-1)^(2/3)/(1 + (-1)^(1/3))/(x + (-1)^(1/3)) - (-1)^(2/3)/(
 1 + (-1)^(1/3))/(x - (-1)^(2/3)) , that is, the denominators are all one degree?

Comment: Edited my answer to address this case as well.

Comment: Very good, Thanks!